# what are the differences between react-form and redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi have anyone used both the forms i want to know what are the differences between those two and which one is better.

- [React-Form](https://react-form.js.org/#/)
- [Redux-Form](https://redux-form.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use Redux-Form.Actually the react-form has been no longer supported.
Here is the information in GitHub about it:(https://github.com/react-tools/react-form)

> UNMAINTAINED
>
> This library is no longer supported and has been deprecated in favor of the following libraries:
> React-Final-Form - A superior libary offering similar and/or better functionality that the original react-form.
>
> Informed - React-Form reimagined and rewritten from scratch by @joepuzzo, a previous maintainer of react-form

---

About the different, react-form is much more simple and easy to learn, but redux-form must have redux in your project and should have some basic knowledge about HOC and redux.

The react-form need to handle the data yourself but redux-form use redux to handle the date in project and  create actions、store and so on.